# Odd pandas line chart using ggplot theme

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to use pandas for plotting using the ggplot theme.

Here is my sample dataframe:

```
seasonname Core-no season Fall/Winter Spring/Summer Summery Core True Summer   
date_utc                                                                       
2015-06-01       199.7825    111.1363      180.3559     166.6217     66.3297   
2015-06-02       201.9999    111.9228      158.2303     153.7611     54.7868   
2015-06-03       169.8468    108.4291      137.1497     118.4648     55.1780   
2015-06-04       164.2676    108.7186      160.1299     140.5675     46.6883   
2015-06-05       144.8806     71.8517      113.8878     111.8050     31.0500   
2015-06-06       122.1885     76.7588      111.0260      92.0495     26.9652   
2015-06-07        79.8287     32.7678       41.0086      54.5739     19.5470   
2015-06-08       193.2663    125.5355      172.7237     145.4507     47.1553   
2015-06-09       175.1136     89.9360      164.2935     144.5485     52.4961   
2015-06-10       167.5729     88.9686      125.5094     153.6020     46.3585
```

When I plot it using the normal pandas theme `df['2015-06':].plot(figsize=(12,10))`, I get:

[image]

However, when I try the ggplot theme, `pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'`, I get this:

[image]

(notice: no axes either)

It looks like a bug to me, but is there something I'm doing wrong? The problem persists when I remove the `figsize` parameter as well. (pandas version 0.18.0, matplotlib version 1.4.2)

Comment: Why don't you give this a try and see : >>>`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
>>> `plt.style.use('ggplot')`. Are there any improvements?

Comment: @NickilMaveli, This was it! Please repost as an answer and I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [`ggplot`](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html) style for customizing plots, you could do:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

To revert back to the default style, you could then do:

```
>>> matplotlib.style.use('default')
```

Comment: And according to a pandas core developer, `pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'` is deprecated.